# How to create an entity that would relate to another one of the same type (recursive entities)

Tags: nestjs

In short: I've got an entity called `Section` and it's supposed to contain a field called `Subsection`. Each section can have many subsections and one subsection can only belong to a single section. So we've got `Many2One` here. The class looks something like this (I copied just a few fields):

```
@Entity('section')
export class SectionEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('increment')
    id: number;

    @Column({
        type: 'int',
        name: 'template_id',
        nullable: true,
    })
    templateId: number;

    @Column({
        type: 'varchar',
        name: 'name',
    })
    name: string;

    @Column({
        type: 'boolean',
        name: 'is_base_template',
    })
    isBaseTemplate: boolean;
}
```

but I need to add another field `subsections` of type `SectionEntity`. So in that case it will look like a recursive type.

How do I do that and what relations (the decorators) will look like then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that this is actually a Typeorm question from the decorated entity.There is a support for it in Typeorm, you can find a good example [here](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/sample/sample8-self-referencing/entity/Category.ts). 
In this case it would look something like this:

```
@Entity('section')
export class SectionEntity {
   @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('increment')
   id: number;

   @Column({
      type: 'int',
      name: 'template_id',
      nullable: true,
   })
   templateId: number;

   @Column({
      type: 'varchar',
      name: 'name',
   })
   name: string;

   @Column({
      type: 'boolean',
      name: 'is_base_template',
   })
   isBaseTemplate: boolean;

   @ManyToOne(type => SectionEntity, section => section.subsections)
   parentSection: SectionEntity;

   @OneToMany(type => SectionEntity, section => section.parentSection)
   subsections: SectionEntity[];
}
```

Comment: It works like a charm! Brilliant, thank you ever so much once again. You've saved my day, mate!

Comment: Would please have a look at another question of mine, in a way related to the issue discussed here? Here is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62314903/saving-and-working-with-a-self-referencing-entity-in-typeorm